# PHP and mysql: previously working code: Saving Data and images to database or filepath

Tags: php, mysql, file

I'm trying to save some data and a couple of images from a form to my database.
I previously had a part of the code that worked (the part that saved the data and images to the database) now for some reason it is not working, - I was messing around with the code and pressed undo one too many times.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
session_start();
/*** connect to db ***/
      $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_USERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $title = $_POST["title"];
            $authors = $_POST["authors"];
            $description = $_POST["description"];
            $price = $_POST["price"];
            $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  
            $content = $_FILES['content']['tmp_name']; 
            $target_dir = "/path/to/dir/";   
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["content"]["name"]);



//move file
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES["content"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2) ) {
        echo "The files have been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }

$file_path=$target_dir. basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$file_path2=$target_dir. basename( $_FILES["content"]["name"]);
echo $file_path;


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into books values('".$_POST["title"]."','".$_POST["authors"]."','".$_POST["description"]."', '".$_POST["price"]."','".$file_path."', '".$file_path2."')");

$stmt->execute();


}
```

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong here? How can I get the images to upload and the images saving back in the database?
There are no error messages I am just presented with a page that says 'error'as I've echoed in the code

Comment: As the problem seems to be with the call to `move_uploaded_file()`, you should check all variables involved there and check if the paths are writable. And the point of a prepared statement is to prepare a statement and bind the variables to avoid sql injection. You should not inject your user input directly in the query.

Comment: Thanks, the paths are writable but i'll work on improving the security when the basics are working.